# I suggest that he can

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives

Can we use modal verbs in subjunctive mood? I haven't been able to find any information about any modal verbs but the fact that *should* can be used.

1. I suggest that he can swim, as unless you're able to swim, you can easily drown.

Comment: What do you intend your sentence to mean? The latter part suggests that you want to say _I suggest that he should learn to swim_. I would understand _I suggest that he can swim_ to mean _I suggest that it's probable that he is able to swim_.

Comment: As for the official question, there is no "subjunctive mood" in English, and it's not brought on by use of the verb _suggest_, which normally takes a _that_-clause, but may take an untensed one under certain circumstances. Of course, since modals are untensed, you can't tell a clause beginning with a modal from one intended to be tenseless. The solution is to think of "subjunctive" as just another modal construction, like _had better_ or _gotta_.

Answer (score 1):

There is no subjunctive mood of English verbs, at least there is nothing like the subjunctive in Spanish or other Romance languages. There are subjunctive clauses which occur as subordinate clauses in a matrix clause with verbs like "suggest" or "recommend". The subjunctive clause features the bare infinitive form of the verb.  Even then, there is no requirement for the verb to be in the infinitive form.

So, as a learner, you may want to use a subjunctive once or twice a year, perhaps less. They really aren't very important!

As the subjunctive uses the bare infinitive, and as modal verbs are defective and don't inflect to the third person normally the whole question is a bit unanswerable.  I know that something subjunctive is happening in "I suggest that he write a book"  because "write" is a bare infinitive, likewise "I suggest that he writes a book" doesn't use the bare infinitive.  There is no way to determine from syntax or morphology or meaning if "I suggest that he can write a book" is a bare infinitive and subjunctive or not.

Now instead of subjunctive moods, English uses modal verbs very freely.  It is normal to say "He should write a book". In some languages this would be expressed with the subjunctive.  In English we use modal verbs instead.

<sub>There are some idioms like "God save the Queen" that preserve the old English subjunctive.  But these are exceptions</sub>